# Material UI toggle button design

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

Here is the toggle button I want to put on my page

[image]

I didn't find any material-ui component/api to implement it.
Should I build a custom toggle button with css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Material UI Toggle button and override the styles but that will probably be more work than it is worth. If it were me I would just do it custom.